# Displaying terms based on loop posts?

Tags: loop, query-posts, taxonomy, shortcode, terms

I have a shortcode that shows a loop for a custom post type:

```
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();  
   // do something
endwhile;
```

Some of the posts are in categories ($term->name), how do I display list of these categories and posts within them **based on that loop**?

Example:

I have 2 categories - "Foo" and "Bar", I have 5 posts in "Foo" and 5 posts in "Bar".

I'm displaying all the posts and get something like this below them:

> Foo (5) | Bar (5)

But in different loop I'm using posts_per_page() limiter, and I'm displaying only 3 posts, not 10, so I want to get:

> Foo (3)

I was trying something like this:

```
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 

   $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'portfolio_categories');  

   foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
      $draught_links[] = $term->name;
   }

   var_dump($draught_links);

    // do something
endwhile;
```

But doing foreach inside of while loop is messy and I'm getting something like

> Foo (1) Foo (2) Foo (3) Foo (4) Foo (5) Foo (5) Bar (1) Foo (5) Bar
>   (2) ...

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to output how many posts are in a category in a loop or in single posts?

Comment: Each post is only in one category (or not) so I'm trying to display how many posts are in certain category in a loop. The problem is `foreach` doesn't work like expected within `while` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try the following options.

`wp_list_categories` with the `'show_count'` parameter
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories

`get category` and use `$count = $category->category_count;`
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category

You can traverse up the functions to `get_term` if those don't work and see what is in there, even though you probably can use `get the terms` you will have to parse the array for output as can be seen in your example, so the above 2 methods would most likely be better.